# Passing javascript a variable as a string

Tags: javascript, android, asp.net

**Quick details:** I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 displayed on an Android applications WebView

In my web application I have javascript similar to the following

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

I wish to pass the current user account to the android through the string 'toast'.

I've tried several different methods to pass the account name as a string to the android but none have worked, and I think it's because the javascript is executed on a new thread. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Have you enabled javascript in WebView settings?

Comment: Yes, see my reply to the answer below to see where my problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

I'm editing the previous answer,since the requirements of this question are very different from the title posed. This is not about how to pass Javascript variable as a string to android's (java) class. This is more of a question related to the interaction between Android's frame-work and ASP.NET web service.  So, hereby I'm posting one of the links which deals with this topic extensively (a well written article) http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/304302/Calling-Asp-Net-Webservice-ASMX-From-an-Android-Ap. [NOTE: This solution utilizes the KSOAP library jar for android platform. ]

Basically you would want to have one of the web service methods return the logged-in user, this method can be invoked by Android's native java class (for e.g. let's call it 'soapActivity'). Now, in order to convey this info to the webView from the java class 'soapActivity', use the addJavascriptInterface() method of your webView instance variable.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am able to pass a defined string through 'toast' but I was wondering how it would be possible to store the current user log-in name in 'toast'. eg. In my controller I can set up the savepath with the users log-in details by using "`HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`" but I'm unsure how to implement this into the view and have it stored in 'toast'.

Comment: As far as I understand HttpContext.User.Identity.Name provides the  user's name currently logged in to the Windows Operating System. But this information is known only to ' ASP.NET MVC 4' framework, not to Android's webView. Its just a browser, it does not (in fact should not) have the capability to decipher details such as current user logged into the ASP.NET framework. This information has to be conveyed from the ASP.NET framework through some java script interface to Android, I'm afraid its inevitable.

Comment: When I use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` it returns the username of the person logged into the web service. The thing is, when I use a WebView in the android application and then log into the ASP.NET web service, `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` works but when I'm using the `JavascriptInterface` on the android, because it is in a new thread it doesn't associate with the logged in webview and doesn't recognize `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` and essentially isn't even logged in. But my question is that which you've stated, how do I go about setting the 'toast' string to pass username?

Comment: Please clarify a couple of things? First of all , does the toast String which is being passed as an argument to the function showAndroidToast(toast) in your javascript code, already contain the desired user info? Or does the toast String needs to be populated with this info before passing it to Android'd context.

Comment: No it doesn't. That is what my question basically is, how do I populate this info into the toast string? The function is triggered by a button click using this code in the view `<input type="button" value="Scan Fingerprint" onclick="showAndroidToast('Scanning Complete')" />`. Is it possible to set a model parameter to a string and have it stored in toast or put into the  `Android.showToast()` function?

Comment: @Yorimitsu : Please review the updated answer to this post. I hope it guides you in the right direction.